# Problem displaying an absolute div in an another horizontal scrollable div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal scrollable list where i can add extendable panel.

It is working fine with few data, problem is, when the list go out of the screen, my display is broken. To resolve this problem i added an overflow hidden property on my list. But i lost my main functionnality : the displayable panel.
Any idea how to resolve my problem?

I add example of both of my case.

```
<div class="positionning">
  <div class="top">  
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="panelRight">
      example of content
      </div>
    <div class="mainList">
      <div class="card">
    <div class="inner">
      data detail
    </div>
      </div>

      [...]
      <div class="card">
    <div class="inner">
      data detail
    </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
</div>



.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}

.panelRight {
  order: 2;
}

.mainList {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.card {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.card.inner {
    display: none;
}

.card:hover {
  overflow: visible;
}

.inner:hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

here is what i change

http://jsfiddle.net/gfy9j4mc/64/

```
.mainList {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfy9j4mc/65/

```
.mainList {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Thanks.

ps: edited

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: life saver! once the solution implemented i'll post it. Thks!

Comment: there is no another way than using js ? can't it be done only with css3?

Comment: You could make the wrapper element higher to begin with, so that it can accommodate for “raised” card content … and then play around with negative margins and maybe putting the background color on a different element to get the same optics again.